# How did subversion get on my iMac

Tags: unix, svn, lua

I retired and am teaching myself Unix, and C with anticipation of learning LUA after that in an effort to keep 'the little grey cells' active
Therefore, in using Unix I have discovered files that I know nothing about, nor does unix man. I found .subversion and related files on my computer and I sure do not remember installing them. I have googled and left questions on Apple community. But I thought that I would try asking here, and hope that this is not too general a question(s)?

Does this thing come imbedded in downloads, say LUA or something from GCC?

Can I just go ahead and delete all things subversion?

Thank you

Comment: This is an admin question rather than a programming question. Nonetheless, Subversion is a tool used by programmers, so, Shippy, you could learn to use it and/or [git]. Revision control is the programmer's second tool, right after [executable specifications/automated tests)](https://github.com/arnaudbrejeon/cspec/blob/master/examples/sample/fabs_desc.c).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subversion and [many many other open source](http://www.apple.com/opensource/) apps come preinstalled on your mac - it was there when you got it.

I'd recommend not deleting it - It's not hurting anything and trying to 'clean up' could lead to some unintended consequences.

Some other places to check out on the quest to keep the gray cells going:

- https://apple.stackexchange.com/  -- all things mac and apple
- https://serverfault.com/ -- questions relating to administrating and
  running your machine.

Comment: Thank you for your answers all. To thekbb I appreciate knowing that it is preinstalled. That answered this question.